# Mysql who is locking the row?

Tags: java, mysql, percona

is there a way that can give who is locking the current row?
my ERP need to check if the record is locked for update by other user or not.
I'm using mysql(Percona) server & Java SE as end client application.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14257/how-can-i-find-who-holds-the-lock-based-on-the-hex-dumped

Comment: Are you locking tables with `LOCK TABLES`? If yes, why are you even trying to do it that way? Control the access level via your application, not via MySQL. Usually, all apps connect using one MySQL user, even if you can obtain who issued the lock, it will not tell you **who** was it, it'll tell you the session that did it. This should be application controlled, not MySQL controlled.

Comment: Good answer, I'm using row locking criteria not table locking, any way that what I'm locking for, I'm using java, is there a code sample to get the session that did it?!!

Answer (score 0):

Use select for update , for lock

SELECT field_Name FROM table_Name FOR UPDATE;

Comment: i need to return a direct message to the another client that this record is locked by another user.

Comment: I think you don't need to do anything , the lock message is auto reply to the user when other user is update the record.